# How do I correctly output META-INF when libraries use SPIs using gradle?

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, lucene, build.gradle

I am attempting to make a test application using Gradle and Java that uses several libraries that use the Java Service Provider interface. I think this means that I need to modify `META-INF` but I am not really sure how to do this.

The error that I get is `An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.codec with name`Lucene50`does not exist. You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath. The current classpath supports the following names [ SimpleText]`

I think that I need to get the SPI information into META-INF but I am not sure how to do this with Gradle.

Specifically, I am trying to use Lucene and Hadoop jars in the following build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group:'org.apache.lucene', name:'lucene-core', version:'5.0.0'
    compile group:'org.apache.lucene', name:'lucene-queryparser', version:'5.0.0'
    compile group:'org.apache.lucene', name:'lucene-analyzers-common', version:'5.0.0'
    compile group:'org.apache.lucene', name:'lucene-facet', version:'5.0.0'
    compile group:'org.apache.lucene', name:'lucene-codecs', version:'5.0.0'

    compile group:'org.apache.hadoop', name:'hadoop-hdfs', version:'2.6.0'
    compile group:'org.apache.hadoop', name:'hadoop-core', version:'1.2.1'
    compile group:'org.apache.hadoop', name:'hadoop-common', version:'2.6.0'

}

jar
        {

                from {configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory() ?it:zipTree(it) }}
                manifest
                        {
                            attributes 'Main-Class': 'LuceneTest'
                        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `lucene-core` and `lucene-codecs` libraries provide `org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` implementations, so they both have a `META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` service file. When you merge all your dependencies, both files are added to the jar file, but Lucene only sees the `lucene-codecs` one. You could merge the service files manually in the `jar` task, as in [this post](http://cmoz.me/blog/2014/11/service-files-uber-jars-and-gradle/), which basically finds all the service files and combines them. The easier solution is probably to use something like the [Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

If you add this to `build.gradle`, using the `shadowJar` task instead of the `jar` task should do what you want.

```
buildscript {
  repositories { jcenter() }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.1'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
shadowJar {
  mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Went with the first option from the blog post